# WordPress custom category page shows blank page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display a posts from a specific category on a WordPress website. The category code is 31. Here is my code,

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: SSLive
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">



<?php 
$args = array ( 'category' => 31, 'posts_per_page' => 5);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
 ?>
//Style Posts here
<?php endforeach; ?>


    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The issue that I am facing is that when I use this page, nothing shows up.

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Can you `var_dump( $myposts );` ?

Comment: You've opened `<?php get_header(); ?>` with an opening PHP tag without closing your previous one.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you call using wp_query? Nice and easy to use, this simple script should return you a linked title for each of the posts in your category. Adding additional informatio is easy as this is just like the main wordpress loop so all the generic calls will work i.e. `the_content`, `the_excerpt` etc.

```
       <?php
          $args = array( 'cat' => 31,);
          $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
          $loop->the_post();
       ?> 
       <!--- Add your stuff here --->
       <!--- Title for example --->
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
       <?php
          endwhile;
       ?>
```